# Sync data from Web Server to iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, web-services

I felt completely lost in something that sounds trivial. From what i understand, my client wants to have some kind of behaviour that happens in android, called auto-sync.

I'm building an app with view controllers, that have data retrieved from a server. Every view controller shows either a list of objects, or just one object.

When the app comes from background, my client wants a request to happen, asking the server if there are any new objects to retrieve. If the answer is yes, i receive the view controllers that i should update, and when i'm on those view controllers that show those objects, i should make a request to receive the new objects and update my list or view.

There should be no notifications back and forth, because this is gonna be a internal process of the app, to keep it always updated.

So, my client asked me to build this behaviour and have a cache system working. Are there any good practices, or solutions to achieve this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coming from a JavaScript background, I'll give you my answer that would work on a Cordova type mobile application running on JavaScript.

1) Create a local database on your mobile device and store all the objects in there.
2) Create a table in your database to store the "last sync" date and time.
3) Set up an API endpoint on your server to accept a "last sync" parameter and return all newer data than the last sync date and time.
4) On every page load, make a request to the API to retrieve the latest information and save it in the local database.
5) On every subsequent page loads, load the new data. (as user experience)

Now, there is a different way if you do not want to constantly make API calls on every page load.

Set up a socket connection between the mobile app and the server.
http://socket.io

This will allow you to "push" down new data everytime the server database is updated.

When a user opens up the app for the first time, make an API call to get all the updates and register on a socket.io channel for live updates.

The most crucial thing to cater for is when an API call terminates prematurely and looses some info. Only update your "last sync" date time on successful updates.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good answer is use core data. Then sync the local results as needed, while making the request and merging the local and server response. You'll have to decide which reference wins.